# Extracting information from string and creating new variable

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a column with big character strings like this:

```
"[{'tipoTeste': 'RT-PCR', 'estadoTeste': 'Concluído',
'dataColetaTeste': {'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2021-12-30T03:00:00.000Z'}, 
'resultadoTeste': 'Detectável', 'loteTeste': None, 
'fabricanteTeste': None, 'codigoTipoTeste': '1', 'codigoEstadoTeste': '3', 
'codigoResultadoTeste': '1', 'codigoFabricanteTeste': None}]"
```

And i want to create another variable called Date with the date information inside this huge string, in this case is `2021-12-30`

Im not managing to grep this date information for all rows....

Comment: does your string contain `\n` ie linebreaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}")
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "2021-12-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `parse_date` directly on the string

```
library(parsedate)
> as.Date(parse_date(str1))
[1] "2021-12-30"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "[{'tipoTeste': 'RT-PCR', 'estadoTeste': 'Concluído',
'dataColetaTeste': {'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2021-12-30T03:00:00.000Z'}, 
'resultadoTeste': 'Detectável', 'loteTeste': None, 
'fabricanteTeste': None, 'codigoTipoTeste': '1', 'codigoEstadoTeste': '3', 
'codigoResultadoTeste': '1', 'codigoFabricanteTeste': None}]"
```